# How to prove $f \in L^p(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f \ge 0$, $f\in L^1(0,1)$, monotone decrease. Suppose $\forall a,x \in (0,1) $ such that $0<x-a<x+a<1$,
$$\int_{x-a}^x f(t)dt<\frac{5}{4} \int_{x}^{x+a}f(t)dt.$$
Prove $f\in L^p(0,1)$, $\forall 1\le p\le \frac{\ln 2}{\ln 3-\ln 2}$.

I can get a weaker bound $1\le p<\frac{\ln 2}{\ln25 - \ln16}$ by dividing the interval of integration by $[2^{-n},2^{-n+1}]$ and getting $f(2^{-n})<\frac{25}{16}f(2^{-n+1})$, but I don't know how to get a finer bound.

My attempt,
$$
2^{-n}f(2^{-n})<\int_0^{2^{-n}} f(t)dt<\frac{5}{4}\int_{2^{-n}} ^{2^{-n+1}} f(t)dt<\frac{25}{16}\int_{2^{-n+1}} ^{2^{-n+2}} f(t)dt<2^{-n}f(2^{-n+1}),
$$
thus, $$f(2^{-n})<\frac{25}{16}f(2^{-n+1})<\left(\frac{25}{16}\right)^nf(1).$$
Then,
$$
\int_0^1 f(t)^p<\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}2^{-n}f(2^{-n})^p<f(1)^p\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{25}{16}\right)^{np}\cdot2^{-n},
$$
if $\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{25}{16}\right)^p<1$, we can get $\int_0^1 f(t)^p<+\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we follow OP's idea, the issue seems is at the last step of

$$x f(x) \le \int_{0}^x f(t) dt \le A\int_{x}^{2x} f(t) dt \le A^2 \int_{2x}^{3x} f(t) dt$$

where $A = \frac{5}{4}$.

This step relaxes too much. Since the inequality is applied twice. So maybe a good strategy is to use once. That is

$$ \int_{0}^x f(t) dt \le A\int_{x}^{2x} f(t) dt \le A x f(x). $$

While the LHS is

$$ \int_{0}^x f(t) dt = \int_{0}^{x/2} f(t) dt + \int_{x/2}^x f(t) dt \ge \frac{x}{2} f(\frac{x}{2}) + \frac{x}{2} f(x) $$

Therefore $$(2 A - 1) f(x) \ge f(\frac{x}{2})$$ which means $$\frac{3}{2} f(x) \ge f(\frac{x}{2}). $$

Then follow OP's steps, it is done.

---

Followup. To find a better $p$, one can set

$$ \int_{0}^x f(t) dt = \int_{0}^{\beta x/2} f(t) dt + \int_{\beta x/2}^x f(t) dt \ge \frac{\beta x}{2} f(\frac{\beta x}{2}) + (1-\frac{\beta}{2})x f(x) $$

Thus $$\left(A - 1 +\frac{\beta}{2}\right) f(x) \ge \frac{\beta}{2} f(\frac{\beta x}{2})$$

then convergence means $$\left|\frac{2A - 2 + \beta}{\beta}\right|^p \frac{\beta}{2} < 1\Rightarrow p < \frac{\log(2/\beta)}{\log(0.5+\beta)/\beta}$$

The maximum is at $\beta = 0.5$ (because of [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=max%20log%282%2Fx%29%20%2F%20log%28%280.5%2Bx%29%2Fx%20%29) :)) which makes $p < 2$.

Comment: (+1) That was great!

Comment: thanks, it is a nice problem.

Comment: Thanks for proving a stronger conclusion, great proof！

Answer (score 4):

Under condition (1) in the OP, it is enough to assume that $f$ is nonnegative, monotone decreasing and locally integrable in $(0,1]$, that is
$\int_If<\infty$ where $I$ is a closed bounded subinterval in $(0,1]$.

Let $A=\frac54$. Following Yimin's, we have that for all $x>0$ and $a>0$ such that $0<a<x<1-a$
$$
\frac{a\big(f(x-\frac{a}{2})+f(x)\big)}{2}\leq\int^{x-\frac{a}{2}}_{x-a}f+\int^x_{x-\frac{a}{2}}f=\int^x_{x-a}f<A\int^{x+a}_x<A af(x)$$
Then
$$f(x-\frac{a}{2})+f(x)<2Af(x)$$
and so,
$$f(x-\frac{a}{2})<(2A-1)f(x)= \frac32f(x)$$

Notice that for any $0<\theta<1$, $a=\theta x$ satisfies
$0<a<x<1-\theta x$ for all $x\in(0,(1+\theta)^{-1}]$. Thus, for all $x\in(0,(1+\theta)^{-1}]$
$$f\Big(x\big(1-\frac{\theta}{2}\big)\Big)<\frac32f(x)$$

Define $x_n=x\big(1-\frac{\theta}{2}\big)^n$. Then
$$x_{n-1}-x_n=x\big(1-\frac{\theta}{2}\big)^{n-1}\frac{\theta}{2}$$
and
$$ f(x_n)\leq A^nf(x)$$.
Putting things together, we obtain that
$$\int_{(0,x]}f^p=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\int^{x_{n-1}}_{x_n}f^p<\frac{x\theta}{2}f^p(x)\sum^\infty_{n=1}\Big(\frac32\Big)^{pn}\Big(1-\frac{\theta}{2}\Big)^{n-1}$$
The answer to the OP follows.

---

**Edit:**
My original approach was to following the OP's idea and propose the following  strategy:

Notice that for any $0<x<1$ and $0<a<x$ so that $x+a<1$,
$$f(x)<\frac1a\int^x_{x-a}f<\frac54\frac1a\int^{x+a}_xf\leq\Big(\frac54\Big)^2\frac1a\int^{x+2a}_{x+a}f\leq \Big(\frac54\Big)^2f(x+a)$$
In particular, for any $0<x<1$ and $a>0$ with $2a<x<1$ we have
\begin{align}
f^p(x-a)&< A^pf^p(x)
\end{align}
where $A=\frac{25}{16}$.

Fix $0<x<1$. Let $a_n$ a sequence of positive numbers such that \begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1}a_n=x\tag{0}\label{zero}
\end{align}
Let $x_0=x$, and $x_n=x-\sum^n_{j=1}a_j$ so that  $x_{n-1}-x_n=a_n$.
If
\begin{align}
2a_n<x_{n-1},\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}
then
$$f^p(x_n)\leq A^pf(x_{n-1})<A^{pn}f^p(x)$$
and so,
$$\int_{(0,x]}f^p=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\int^{x_{n-1}}_{x_n}f^p\leq f^p(x)\sum^\infty_{n=1}A^{np}a_n$$
The series converges if
$$A^p\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{a_n}=A^p\beta<1$$
That yields that $f\in L_p(0,1)$ for all
$$1\leq p<\frac{-\log\beta}{2\log(5/4)}$$
To get the desire bound, one should find a sequence $a_n$ that satisfies in addition
$$\frac{-\log(\beta)}{2\log(5/4)}\approx\frac{\log2}{\log(3/2)},$$
that  $\beta_0=\exp\Big(-\frac{(\log 4)\log(5/4)}{\log(3/2)}\Big)\approx 0.4662968<1$.

I suggest on consider expression of the form
$$\sum_n n^a\beta^n, \qquad a\in\mathbb{R}$$

---

- Geometric series $x=\frac{\beta^k}{1-\beta}=\sum^\infty_{j=0}\beta^{k+j}\leq1$, $k\geq1$, will not work since
  $$2\beta^{k+n}<\sum^\infty_{j=n}\beta^{k+j}=\frac{\beta^{k+n}}{1-\beta}$$
  implies that $2<\frac1{1-\beta}$, that is  $\beta>1/2$.
- The log series $x=-\log(1-\beta)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\beta^n}{n}$ seems not to work either
  $$-\log(1-\beta)-\big(\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}\frac{\beta^k}{k}\Big)=\beta^n\int^1_0 u^{n-1}\frac{1}{(1-\beta(1-u))^n}\, du=\beta^nI_n(\beta)$$
  The integral $I_n(\beta)$ is monotone increasing in $\beta$ and $I_n(1/2)<\frac2n$.

Comment: The integral $I(\beta) = \int_0^1 \frac{u^{n-1}}{ (1 - \beta(1-u) )^n } du$ increases with $\beta$. While this integral $I(0.5) < \frac{2}{n}$.